# How to create `random` value added object for json array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, random

According to the client clicks on `50` or `100` and `500` I  require to create the random `json` objects. I don't how to to create the random object to fit for my json requirement.

I know that we are creating numbers or string generally, but how to create a hole json object itself?

here is what i require to randomize the object of user option:

```
{
    "deviceType": "Kiosi 891,891W Integrated Services Router G2",
    "label": "WAN-EDGE - MOCK1",
    "ip": "192.168.10.2",
    "softwareVersion": "15.1(4)M2",
    "nodeType": "device",
    "family": "Routers",
    "platformId": "CISCO891W-AGN-A-K9",
    "tags": [

    ],
    "role": "BORDER ROUTER",
    "roleSource": "AUTO",
    "customParam": {

    },
    "additionalInfo": {
      "macAddress": "44:d3:ca:1e:72:34"
    },
    "id": "373ce7a8-8843-43ac-879a-283f21abfed1"
}
```

any one help me to randomize the object with all fields which fit with text or number length of each.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to provide more information. I assume you know how to create an object. Assigning random values to properties of an object is then just a tiny step: `var obj = {prop1: Math.random(), prop2: Math.random(), ...};` And to convert it to JSON: `var json = JSON.stringify(obj);`. So I assume there is more to your problem but without more information it's difficult to help.

Comment: Maybe you can use fackerjs to deal with(https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like below would help?
http://www.json-generator.com/

**Quick Sample**

Sample Definition: Define Repeat (n) to how many random objects you may want.

```
[
  '{{repeat(1)}}',
  {
    deviceType: function (tags) {
      var routers = ['Router G1', 'Router G2'];
      return routers[tags.integer(0, routers.length - 1)];
    },
    label: function (tags) {
      var labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2'];
      return labels[tags.integer(0, labels.length - 1)];
    },
    ip: '{{integer(1, 255)}}.{{integer(1, 255)}}.{{integer(1, 255)}}.{{integer(1, 255)}}',
    softwareVersion: '15.1(4)M2',
    nodeType: 'device',
    family: 'Routers',
    platformId: 'CISCO {{integer(100, 999)}} W-AGN-A-K{{integer(1, 9)}}',
    tags: [
      '{{repeat(3)}}',
      '{{lorem(1, "words")}}'
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It require to add in app itself. I am not able keep this as static

Comment: You could create the json generator definition and may be create enough random objects. I presume this is for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes I agree. But the length of JSON goes to 100+ if so it's not easy. as well I can't predict the length in future. the purpose is totally for testing purpose

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have full domain knowledge to create full randomize json object. I have added a sample to my original post. What I suggest is you may create enough repeats and may be store and randomly get an item from json array and return as a part of your object. For this may be you need to do some what custom implementation.

Comment: Already i am much familar with this. But the thing is, I should not use third party links in my app. nearly it's like I should create my own random object each to crossly set with my sample. But very thanks for you guide and spent time for me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to full random? I have it!

```
class RandomObject {
    constructor(maxFieldsCount) {
        var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxFieldsCount + 1));
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this[this.guid()] = this.guid();
        }
    }

    guid(): string {
        var s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
            s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    }
}
```